# If previous row's field is FALSE then set the current row to null

Tags: google-bigquery

I have this bigquery query that sets FALSE if the timestamp diff of start_date/end_date is greater than 0 in comparison to the expected_start/expected_end date and TRUE if the opposite. So now I want to make a condition whenever it checks each row, if the previous row's Started_on_time/Ended_on_time is FALSE then set that current Started_on_time/Ended_on_time row to null if it has the same "dag_id". The "dag_id" is the name of the specific dag in this table and its the first field in this table think of it as the specific name of the row. I want to make sure it only sets to null if its the same dag_id. The point of this is to resolve the alerts when its FALSE to just one alert from that first row in that specific dag_id and set all the other rows with that "dag_id" to null and I want to do that to all the dag_id's.

In my query The started_on_time and end_on_time are newly made fields made in this query and the second select that calls these 2 is "unrecognized" how would I solve this? How can I call newly made fields made by an "end as".

```js
with summary as (
SELECT *,
    TIMESTAMP_DIFF(start_date, expected_start_date, MINUTE) AS Difference_Start_Time,
    TIMESTAMP_DIFF(end_date, expected_end_date, MINUTE)     AS Difference_End_Time,
    CASE
        WHEN TIMESTAMP_DIFF(start_date, expected_start_date, MINUTE) <= 0 THEN TRUE
        WHEN TIMESTAMP_DIFF(start_date, expected_start_date, MINUTE) > 0 THEN FALSE
        END AS Started_On_Time,
CASE
        WHEN TIMESTAMP_DIFF(end_date, expected_end_date, MINUTE) <= 0 THEN TRUE
        WHEN TIMESTAMP_DIFF(end_date, expected_end_date, MINUTE) > 0 THEN FALSE
        END AS Ended_On_Time,
    CASE
        WHEN end_date is null then 'FAILED'
        ELSE 'COMPLETED'
        END AS end_date_tracker,
FROM `np-inventory-planning-thd.IPP_SLA.sla_table`
)

SELECT *,
    CASE
        WHEN
        LAG(started_on_time) OVER (PARTITION BY dag_id ORDER BY start_date ASC) = FALSE
        OR
        LAG(ended_on_time) OVER (PARTITION BY dag_id ORDER BY start_date ASC) = FALSE
        THEN NULL ELSE "ERROR" END AS LAG_CHECK,

        FROM `np-inventory-planning-thd.IPP_SLA.sla_table`
```

Comment: The capitalization of your `Started_On_Time` and `Ended_On_Time` on the 1st query is different on the second query. Can you try removing the capitalization on the first character on both fields on the 1st query?

Comment: Hi, I tried that but it still did not work. Am I able to call fields that have not been actually created in the table but in query using "end as"

Comment: You are not referencing `summary` in our main query. Try changing `np-inventory-planning-thd.IPP_SLA.sla_table` to `summary` on your **main query**.